# TokenMismatchException when trying to log in with cookies disabled

Tags: authentication, cookies, laravel-5

I tried to log into my laravel 5.1.* application with cookies disabled in chromium browser. I got a

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:
```

How can I avoid this and simply redirect to the login page if cookies are disabled?

---

It is the same with every form, that has a CSRF-token, for example an image upload form. A redirect back with message 'please activate cookies' would be nice. Or, perhaps a custom error page.

Comment: are you using <form> tag or {!! Form::open() !!}

Comment: I use <form> but with this: `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">`. The problem occurs only when I disable cookies in the browser

Comment: What is your session driver?

Comment: `SESSION_DRIVER=database`

Comment: @haheute Did you ever solve this?

Comment: not yet, I did not yet try again. Perhaps it is possible to catch the exception with the exception handler.. http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors